# FloatingActionButton desalinhado

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá

Tenho uma TableLayout criada dinamicamente, e quero inserir um FAB na tela. O problema é que não consigo o alinhamento normal, no canto direito inferior.

Estou esquecendo algum parâmetro? Segue o código que estou usando:

```js
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
        
        FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p =  new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        p.setAnchorId(R.id.viewpagerOpcao);
        p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END | Gravity.RIGHT;
        fab.setLayoutParams(p);
        fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.design_fab_background));
        fab.setClipToOutline(true);
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent criar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainOpcao.class);
                startActivity(criar);
            }
        });
```

Para chamar este método, faço "tabela.addView(getFAB());" onde tabela é uma TableLayout.

[image: Screenshot com o FAB desalinhado]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema trocando o LayoutParams de CoordinatorLayout para TableLayout. Mas não entendi ainda o motivo de o primeiro não ter funcionado. Agradeço se alguém puder explicar.

O código novo ficou assim:

```js
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
        FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams p = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.gravity =  Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.END;
        p.setMarginEnd(16);
        fab.setLayoutParams(p);
        fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.design_fab_background));
        fab.setClipToOutline(true);
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent criar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainOpcao.class);
                startActivity(criar);
            }
        });
        return fab;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro é simples em Coordenator Layout tens de utilizar o constraint set para alinhar as views neste caso ficaria assim:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId());
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

O método gravity funciona bem em layout simples como Linear o Relative